# How to run a .sh file in terminal on login

Tags: login, startup, .desktop, .sh

so I have a simple sh file I want to run whenever someone logs in. I tried adding it to startup applications. This didn't work. I tried editing the .desktop file for the startup application to set Terminal=true. This made it open temporarily but shut it down.
I tried editing .bashrc by adding the command bash /path/to/my/file.sh and it had the same effect. This seems like it should be really simple to do, even in linux, but I have tried lots of ways and had no success. I am on Ubuntu 14.something.

Comment: All of those methods should have worked (well, the `.bashrc` one is only on opening a Terminal; `.profile` would have been better). What are you doing inside the .sh file? Is the executable bit set? Does it start with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: As @saiarcot895 you may forgot to give executable permissions to file.

Comment: You would be able to find out what filetype it is set to by typing in `ls -la`

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the script in question. Also, please clarify if you want this to run for a single user or for all users.

Comment: You can try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/704768/run-script-on-login-script-with-sudo-or-startup `/etc/profile.d`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Question --> "so I have a simple sh file I want to run whenever someone logs in. I tried adding it to startup applications."

Suppose path of your file is /home/foster/Desktop/script.sh

First make it executable by :

```
$ chmod +x /home/foster/Desktop/script.sh
```

Now just Add path of the script to file "/etc/rc.local" :

```
sh /home/foster/Desktop/script.sh
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `Terminal=true` in the desktop file, the terminal window by default closes after the "the job has finished".  An easy solution is to change your (terminal-) profile settings:

- open a terminal window, choose Profile Preferences
- choose "Title & Command" (at least that is what it is in Dutch, the second tab)
- in the section "when the command has finished" choose "keep terminal window open"

And of course, like you did, in the desktop file, set `Terminal=true`

[image]