# Run script on login (script with sudo) or startup

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
ids=$(xinput list | awk '/SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse .*pointer/ {print $8}' | sed 's/id=\(.*\)/\1/')

if [ -z "$ids" ]; then
  exit 0;
fi

read -a ids_array <<< $ids

echo fixing id ${ids_array[0]}
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration' 1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1

echo fixing id ${ids_array[1]}
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1.5
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration' 1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1

sudo sensei-raw-ctl --show
sudo sensei-raw-ctl --polling 500
sudo sensei-raw-ctl --cpi-on 450
sudo sensei-raw-ctl --cpi-off 5670

unset ids
unset ids_array
```

I wish for the following script to run once when I login or when the computer starts up. The above script is located in `/home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh`.

I DO NOT wish to use the GUI to add the script. I wish to learn a bit more about how to do it manually.

**What files do I need to create, what must be in them and where should they be located to be able to run my script which is located in the said directory.**

Comment: Here they explain how to run an script at boot as root (in /etc/init) as user (/home/user/.config/upstart) or even with a "@reboot" task in cron:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: Either rclocal or systemd on a newer system as seen in the posted link.

Comment: @Julen creating a cronjob is **not** the right solution, as *@reboot* starts the script when the system is started, not when the user logs in. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## 1. Using /etc/profile.d

You can run the script **on login** by placing the script in */etc/profile.d/*

These files are [executed upon login](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fprofile.d.2F.2A.sh).

To create a symbolic link to the file you want to execute, use

> sudo ln -s /home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh
>   /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh

## 2. Using [upstart](https://launchpad.net/upstart)

Another possibility is to use [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id300)

> start on desktop-session-start

and place your script there.

Comment: How does this handle sudo commands?

Comment: @KarlMorrison *echo "password" | sudo -S command*

Comment: Where is that supposed to reside? In the file?  You need to be a little more specific (I'm still learning this stuff!).

Comment: @KarlMorrison personally I think you should use the *upstart* solution, as */etc/profile.d* is not really meant to be used like this. My suggestion is more a "hack". I you still want to try, just add the *echo "password"* in front of the *| sudo -S* part, whereafter sudo won't ask for the password any more.

Comment: Indeed I've tried: https://askubuntu.com/questions/704815/upstart-not-running-sh-script perhaps you could see whats wrong? :/

Comment: @KarlMorrison I think the error is with the part *start on runlevel [2345]*.  Use the solution I suggest: *start on desktop-session-start* which I think is what you want: starting when the desktop session starts. - no? (Regarding *upstart* I will respond in your other ticket)

Comment: Just tried with what you suggested, still no effect :( I need the script to be loaded when the login screen appears (as the mouse can be used there). So basically before logging into the user.

Comment: Please check in your related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/704815/upstart-not-running-sh-script/704820#704820