# Upstart not running .sh script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, startup, upstart

The information on the web regarding `upstart`, `init` and `.conf` files is rubbish. A lot of different places show completely different ways of doing things.

Anyways, I have a script file `/home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh` (file permission 775):

```
#!/bin/bash
# run as root

xinput list >> /var/log/trololol.log

echo trololol start >> /var/log/trololol.log

ids=$(xinput list | awk '/SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse .*pointer/ {print $8}' | sed 's/id=\(.*\)/\1/')

echo trololol before ids >> /var/log/trololol.log
echo $ids >> /var/log/trololol.log
echo trololol after ids >> /var/log/trololol.log

if [ -z "$ids" ]; then
  exit 0;
fi

read -a ids_array <<< $ids

echo fixing id ${ids_array[0]}
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration' 1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[0]} 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1

echo fixing id ${ids_array[1]}
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1.5
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration' 1
xinput set-prop ${ids_array[1]} 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1

sensei-raw-ctl --show
sensei-raw-ctl --polling 500
sensei-raw-ctl --cpi-on 450
sensei-raw-ctl --cpi-off 5670

unset ids
unset ids_array

echo sensei-raw-startup.sh script `date` >> /var/log/sensei-raw-startup.log

echo trololol end >> /var/log/trololol.log
```

When logged in running the script as `sudo` it runs perfectly (log is also created):

```
karl@karl-laptop:~/.scripts/startup$ sudo bash sensei-raw-startup.sh 
fixing id 12
fixing id 14
Backlight intensity: low
Backlight pulsation: slow
Speed in CPI (LED is off): 5670
Speed in CPI (LED is on): 450
Polling frequency: 500Hz
karl@karl-laptop:~/.scripts/startup$
```

Now I wish for this to automatically run whenever I login or the computer starts up (it should affect every user logging in).

I created the file `/etc/init/karl-startup.conf`:

```
description "karls sexy startup script"
author "Karl Morrison"

start on started lightdm

pre-start script
        exec xinput 1> /var/log/karls.log 2>&1
end script

script
        exec bash /home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh
end script
```

Now I check the file with:

```
karl@karl-laptop:~$ init-checkconf /etc/init/karl-startup.conf
File /etc/init/karl-startup.conf: syntax ok
```

I restart my laptop, login and my mouse settings have not been altered, I check the logs:

```
karl@karl-laptop:~$ sudo cat /var/log/trololol.log 
[sudo] password for karl: 
trololol start
trololol before ids

trololol after ids
```

As you can see where the ids are supposed to be displayed *12 14* it's blank.

Got me the following error:

```
karl@karl-laptop:~$ sudo cat /var/log/karls.log
Unable to connect to X server
```

Comment: @muru The only reason I have it is to see if the files are actually being run. If they are the logs will appear. Nothing more than that.

Comment: I'm not sure what the behaviour of `exec` is when multiple `exec` lines are present. That's what `script end-script` is for.

Comment: @muru Updated question with more info! Seems as if xinput command just will not work under upstart.

Comment: Have you set the `DISPLAY` variable and any other variables that the script needs?

Comment: @muru You are seeing everything I have done :) What must I do with this `DISPLAY` variable?

Comment: Run `sudo bash -c 'echo $DISPLAY'`

Comment: @muru Result: `:0`

Comment: @muru Error: `Unable to connect to X server` when running `exec xinput`

Comment: You need to set `DISPLAY` in the Upstart configuration. See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file */etc/init/karl-startup.conf* should read:

```
description "karls sexy startup script"
```

*As you say in [your related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704768/run-script-on-login-script-with-sudo-or-startup/704810?noredirect=1#comment1035055_704810) you want to start the script **on login**, further use*

```
start on desktop-session-start
```

*if you want to run it on startup, use*

```
start on startup

exec sudo -u $user /home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh
exec echo sensei-raw-startup.sh script `date` >> /var/log/karl-startup.log start
```

Further details on [upstart](https://launchpad.net/upstart) here:
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id300

Comment: In this question, I wish for it to start before login. I tried your changes, still no effect :/

Comment: Ok, I see. Well if it's at reboot I suggest you use a cronjob. Check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command

Comment: Ok tried cronjob: `sudo cronjob -e` and wrote `@reboot /home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh`, still does not change settings :/

Comment: if you don't explicitly use *bash* in front of the path to the script, the file would be executed using sh. I suggest, you use *@reboot bash /home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh*

Comment: Ok added *bash* to the command, still not effecting it!

Comment: Ok I've done more testing and my script *is* being run, however it is not finding the ids of the SteelSeries Sensei Raw Gaming Mouse pointers. Which brings me to ask, when are those loaded (connected via usb)?

Comment: I'll mark this as correct as it does solve my question. I will start another question on why xinput isn't working.